# Grant CREATE CREATE schema to user in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am using data build tool which requires developers to create their own schemas on the fly. I figured this was part of the db_ddladmin role, but apparently not. After some research, I found

```
GRANT CREATE SCHEMA ON DATABASE::[DATABASE] TO [USER]
```

Alternatively `ALTER SCHEMA` instead. However, this seems to have no effect. After dropping db_owner from the user, they are unable to create schemas even after running the above statement. After re-adding db_owner, they are able again.

I would like to avoid setting all developers as db_owners. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like something else is blocking them. With the `db_ddladmin` role, I can create `SCHEMA`. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rB8h.png). Don't forget that `DENY` has a higher precedence than `GRANT`, so if something is `DENY`ing them the ability, they won't be able to `CREATE` a `SCHEMA`.

Comment: `GRANT CREATE SCHEMA` also works, so this very strongly suggests that the `USER`(s) have another permission that is explicitly `DENY`ing them from doing the `CREATE`.